# Java Zip file Export Options

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, multifile-uploader

**My requirement is:**

- User will upload a `.zip` file (which will contain multiple files) via **API**  and I need to send back the files to the user in response.

**My solution 1:**

- returning list of the file download link to user in response.
  but the user is not happy with this solution.

Is there any other way return the list of file?

Comment: Why are they not happy about it?

Comment: when unzipping the file i has use server memory and for download link i am giving the server unzipped file path. so it will use server memory and this API used more frequently which will create memory issue in future. I can't delete the unzip file from server because i don't know when the user is going to download the file.

Comment: Do you mean server disk space?

Comment: yes, Server Disk Space.

Comment: Just store the zipped file and extract individual files as they are requested.

Comment: So it's a very frequently used API, may be there is chance we will get memory error after few day.

Comment: Delete the uploaded zip files after a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution would be to unzip your archive directly in browser using a library like `zip.js` or similar.